# Java syntax with greater than/less than: <> are they class specific?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I've been doing an Android tutorial and encountered a class with the following:

```
public class ImageAndTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
```

Is the `<String>` a form of inheritance by type? Or is it some other Java syntax that I should know about?

The class is:

```
android.widget.ArrayAdapter<String>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is called *generics*. The class within `<` and `>` is a *type parameter*.

This is easiest explained by an example:

An `ArrayList` can store items. If you specify a type parameter like this: `ArrayList<String>` then this array list will store items of `String` type only, (in other words, it will store `String`s only)!

Similarly, the `ArrayAdapter` is "parameterized" by a type as well. The `ArrayAdapter` probably holds a value, and this value will be of the type specified between `<` and `>`, which in your case is `String`.

Useful links:

- [Official trail on Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) (a good starting point)

Answer (score 4):

That's [Java Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

It's like C++ templates.

It says that the ArrayAdapter is backed by an array of Strings. It's mostly useful so when you get/add objects, it's type-safe and you don't have to perform any casting.

Answer (score 3):

This is part of Generics which was introduced in Java1.5,   Sometimes you don't know what type of object you can pass or get, so you can pass a generic type of object `"?"`. In this particular instance, you are passing ArrayAdapter object which contains String objects. you can read more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 1):

This is a Java generic class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html