# What the use of < and > signs when using adapters?

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to Android. Basically done programming in C++. There is a small notation I don't understand. Can Anybody help me with this?

Ex: `HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>)`

My question is what is the use of `<` and `>` signs. Sometimes there is one parameter, sometimes there are more, and some look like a data structure.

Ex: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

Why there are two parameters inside?

sometimes I saw it with a question mark: `AdapterView<?>`.

For what purpose you use the `<` and `>` sign?

This confuse me more than anything else.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063749/java-syntax-with-greater-than-less-than-are-they-class-specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are Java generics..

```
HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>)objectToBeTypecast
```

It specifies that this is not
just an arbitrary HashMap, but a HashMap with Key and its value as a String parameters, written `HashMap < String, String>`. 
We say that HashMap is
a generic interface that takes a type parameters - in this case, String.

To know more about generics, you can have a look [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf)